# Active scss class on a table with horizontal and vertical scroll

Tags: css, angular, datatable, scroll

I'm working on a table with that has many columns and rows so it has an horizontal and vertical scroll.

The first column is fixed and it has a shadow. That shadow is visible only when the user scrolls horizontally.

I created a scss class `active-scroll-shadow`, and that class is active when the user scrolls horizontally.

I want to achieve the same behavior with the table vertical scrolling.

Is there a way to active a class on table vertical scroll event and not the browser scroll?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bklajw-jqcb74?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html,app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts,app%2Ftable-basic-example.css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you are doing with your horizontal scroll, you can get the vertical scroll with the `.scrollTop` property.

```
  onScroll(event) {
    console.log(`scrollLeft: ${this.scrollElem.scrollLeft}`);
    this.ApplyShadow = this.scrollElem.scrollLeft > 5;

    console.log(`scrollTop: ${this.scrollElem.scrollTop}`);
    this.ApplyVerticalShadow = this.scrollElem.scrollTop > 5;
  }
```

You'll probably need another variable just for the vertical shadow (I called it `ApplyVerticalShadow`) and then you can conditionally apply the shadow like you've done with the horizontal shadow. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Idk why It wasn't working before it but works now :)

Comment: @bel Glad you got it working!